# Not the brightest light on the christmas tree

Tags: expression

I vaguely remember a German expression that means "not the sharpest tool in the shed" that can be literally translated to "not the brightest light on the Christmas tree". Is there actually a saying similar to the one I recall, and what is its exact phrasing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There exists the expression

> nicht die hellste Kerze am Baum (sein)

which translates to "Not (being) the brightest candle on the tree", presumably a christmas tree, as we don't put candles on trees that often.

It means someone is not very smart (or bright).

There also exist Variations:

> nicht die hellste Kerze (sein)
>
> nicht die hellste Kerze auf der Torte (sein)

... auf der Torte = ... on the cake

[Article about the expression by a German radio station](https://www.swr.de/swr2/literatur/swr2-wort-der-woche-nicht-die-hellste-kerze-auf-der-torte-mit-ulrich-raulff,article-swr-10990.html)

---

There are a few other expression linking intelligence to light, eg:

- Nicht der/die hellste sein: Not being the brightest
- Keine grosse Leuchte sein: Not being a big lamp

Comment: Another similar way: "Nicht die hellste Birne im Kronleuchter"

Answer (score 8):

It's

> Er ist nicht (gerade) das hellste Licht.

You could add *unter der Sonne*, *am Baume* or similar colourful adverbials depending on the season.

> Er ist keine Leuchte.

is similar and also common.

Comment: "Unter der Sonne" passt bei Licht ziemlich schlecht, denn die Sonne zu überstrahlen fällt ja auch den hellsten artifiziellen Lichtern äußerst schwer - das will man aber nicht ausdrücken, sondern einen Vergleich unter Seinesgleichen, bei Christbaum oder Tortenkerzen.

Answer (score 1):

I know the expressions mentioned in the previous answers; but in parts of Eastern Germany, where I am from, the following expressions are more common:

> - Er ist nicht der hellste in der Birne.
> - Sie ist nicht die hellste in der Birne.

Notice that *Birne* does not only name the fruit (pear), but that it is also used to refer to a light bulb and, colloquially, to a person's head.